# Invalid credentials during ldap authentication in spring api gateway application

Tags: spring, security, ldap

I have Spring api gateway application with LDAP authentication,

security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class ReactiveLdapAuthenticationConfig {

    @Value("${spring.ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${spring.ldap.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.ldap.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {

        BindAuthenticator ba = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        ba.setUserDnPatterns(new String[]{"cn={0},ou=Users,dc=test,dc=com"});
        LdapAuthenticationProvider lap = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ba);

        AuthenticationManager am = new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(lap));

        return new ReactiveAuthenticationManagerAdapter(am);
    }

    @Bean
    public BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource ctx = new LdapContextSource();
        ctx.setUrl(ldapUrl);
        ctx.setUserDn(username);
        ctx.setPassword(password);
        ctx.afterPropertiesSet();
        return ctx;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

When I log in on the home page I see error - "Invalid credentials". But I am sure credentials are correct. I use creds here in my config and it works fine

```
ctx.setUserDn(username);
ctx.setPassword(password);
```

if I set wrong password, e.g.

```
ctx.setPassword(wrong password);
```

I have error - "LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308...."

How can I solve problem during UI auth?